# Array list adapter with button objects

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am new to android app development.i want to create a list view that has only one button per cell of list view.For the adapter of this list view i need to give 'ArrayList' as parameter so that I can add and update list view whenever I need.

Comment: Extend BaseAdapter class , follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for custom listView.

You can put the button or anything you want in `rowlayout.xml`